# run "ls" through NSTask in a Cocoa app not working

Tags: cocoa, nstask

I am testing the use of an NSTask because I want to try to run a bunch of commands within my Cocoa application written in Swift that I usually run in Terminal.

In viewDidLoad I have the following code:

```
    let task = NSTask()
    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe

    task.launchPath = "/usr/bash"
    task.currentDirectoryPath = dir
    task.arguments = ["ls"]

    let file:NSFileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading

    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()

    let data =  file.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let datastring = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("datastring = \(datastring)")
```

The app runs but I am getting the following error:

**Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): launch path not accessible**

Can somebody help me understand what I am doing wrong? What I am trying to do now is to run the ls command and then store the result into an array of strings...

Thanks

Comment: if `ls` is a real example consider using the native Foundation class `NSFileManager` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for starters, `/usr/bash` is not the path to the `bash` executable. You want `/bin/bash`.

Next, it does not work to invoke `/bin/bash ls`, which is the equivalent of what you're doing. At a shell, if you want to give a command for `bash` to process and execute, you would do `/bin/bash -c ls`. So, you want to set the tasks's `arguments` to `["-c", "ls"]`.

However, why are you involving a shell interpreter here, at all? Why not just set the task's `launchPath` to `"/bin/ls"` and run the `ls` command directly? You would either leave the `arguments` unset, if you just want to list the current working directory's contents, or set it to arguments that you would pass to `ls`, such as options or a path (e.g. `["-l", "/Applications"]`).

Comment: task.launchPath = "/bin/bash", task.currentDirectoryPath = dir, task.arguments = ["-c","ls"] got rid of the error. Can you explain why I need to use the -c ?

Comment: Because that's how `bash` works. If you supply a direct argument, it tries to use it as a path to a script file. You were trying to make `bash` interpret `"ls"` as a command string. It only does that when you specify `-c` followed by a command string. See the [`bash` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html).